# Extract Timestamp of latest document in MongoDB using Pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have `mongoDB collection` with columns `filename` and `text`

I want to extract timestamp of latest `document` using `pymongo`

**What I Tried:**

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
host = "127.0.0.1:27017"
client = MongoClient(host)

# print(client)

# Getting a database
db = client['ResumeParsing']
# Getting a collection
coll = db.Resume

print(coll.find({"_id": {"$gt": 1}}).sort([("_id", 1), ("date", -1)]))
```

Which is giving me output as :

```
<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x00000187738CD860>
```

While I want datetime as a result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I find out the solution.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import pymongo

host = "127.0.0.1:27017"
client = MongoClient(host)

db = client['ResumeParsing']

coll = db.Resume

# Convert the output of query into list 
latest_doc = list(db.Resume.find().sort("_id", pymongo.DESCENDING).limit(1))

# use generation_time attribute to get datetime from _id
print(latest_doc[0]['_id'].generation_time)
```

Which is giving me output as:

```
2018-08-27 09:16:56+00:00
```