# (Pymongo) use python script auto add update/insert time to MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

(Pymongo) use python script auto add update/insert time to MongoDB

**I just insert one new data, the time data isn't put the last updated time, and how can I do it?**

- the python code

```
import pymongo
import datetime
import json

def init_db(ip, db, coll):
    myclient = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://' + ip + '/')
    mydb = myclient[db]
    mycol = mydb[coll]

    return mydb, mycol


def insert_db_data(insert_one_or_many, insert_values_json):
    
    if insert_one_or_many == "one":
        x = mycol.insert_one(insert_values_json)

    if insert_one_or_many == "many":
        x = mycol.insert_many(insert_values_json)
    return x


ip_input = input("Enter the ip: ")
exist_DB_name = input("Enter exist DB name: ")
exist_coll_name = input("Enter exist collection name: ")
mydb, mycol  = init_db(ip_input, exist_DB_name, exist_coll_name)


insert_one_or_many = input("U are update one or many values? (ex:one , many): ")
newvalues_str = input("Enter new values: ")


insert_values_json =json.loads(newvalues_str)

x = insert_db_data(insert_one_or_many, insert_values_json)
print(x)
```

- output : we can see the *insert data Mark doesn't contain update time*

```
/* 1 createdAt:2022/10/18 上午11:29:51*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("634e1daf448222e964b0e7b2"),
    "name" : "Mark",
    "Age" : 18,
    "ID" : 100555
},

/* 2 createdAt:2022/10/18 上午10:25:35*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("634e0e9fa1fa85dd0cfe58ed"),
    "name" : "Karry",
    "ID" : 100777,
    "Age" : 18,
    "time" : ISODate("2022-10-17T18:06:49.000+08:00")
},

/* 3 createdAt:2022/10/18 上午10:25:35*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("634e0e9fa1fa85dd0cfe58ec"),
    "name" : "Kson",
    "ID" : 100777,
    "Age" : 67,
    "time" : ISODate("2022-10-17T18:06:49.000+08:00")
},

/* 4 createdAt:2022/10/17 下午6:06:07*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("634d290fa1fa85dd0cfe58eb"),
    "name" : "Kim",
    "ID" : 100777,
    "Age" : 28,
    "time" : ISODate("2022-10-17T18:06:49.000+08:00")
},

/* 5 createdAt:2022/10/14 上午11:27:55*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6348d73be94317989175dc31"),
    "name" : "old Mr.K",
    "ID" : 100428,
    "Age" : 99,
    "time" : ISODate("2022-10-17T17:11:24.000+08:00"),
    "Update_ID" : "99999"
}
```

[(pic) of output: insert data Mark doesn't contain update time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWbkP.png)

I see the system does contain this`/* 1 createdAt:2022/10/18 上午11:29:51*/`,  can we just extract this and add to my time block. Maybe that one of the way

I serach relative discussion, but I still can't get it.
[How to automatically update date fields in mongoDB collection on insert/update documents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57816817/how-to-automatically-update-date-fields-in-mongodb-collection-on-insert-update-d)

---

json.loads : str to json
json.dumps : json to str

Below is to show `insert_values_json`  after `json.loads`:
I print the content and type

```
import pymongo
import datetime
import json

def init_db(ip, db, coll):
    myclient = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://' + ip + '/')
    mydb = myclient[db]
    mycol = mydb[coll]

    return mydb, mycol


def insert_db_data(insert_one_or_many, insert_values_json):
    
    if insert_one_or_many == "one":
        x = mycol.insert_one(insert_values_json)

    if insert_one_or_many == "many":
        x = mycol.insert_many(insert_values_json)
    return x


ip_input = input("Enter the ip: ")
exist_DB_name = input("Enter exist DB name: ")
exist_coll_name = input("Enter exist collection name: ")
mydb, mycol  = init_db(ip_input, exist_DB_name, exist_coll_name)


insert_one_or_many = input("U are update one or many values? (ex:one , many): ")
newvalues_str = input("Enter new values: ")


insert_values_json =json.loads(newvalues_str)
print(insert_values_json)
print(type(insert_values_json))
print("= = = = = = = ")
print("")
insert_values_json['time'] = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

x = insert_db_data(insert_one_or_many, insert_values_json)
print(x)
```

- And output:

```
Enter the ip: localhost:27017
Enter exist DB name: (practice_10_14)-0002
Enter exist collection name: collection_new02cp
U are update one or many values? (ex:one , many): many
Enter new values: [{ "name" : "MM22", "Age" : 33, "ID" : 100333} , { "name" : "MM444", "Age" : 44, "ID" : 100444}, { "name" : "MM555", "Age" : 55, "ID" : 100555}]       

[{'name': 'MM22', 'Age': 33, 'ID': 100333}, {'name': 'MM444', 'Age': 44, 'ID': 100444}, {'name': 'MM555', 'Age': 55, 'ID': 100555}]      

<class 'list'>
= = = = = = =

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\chuan\OneDrive\Desktop\10.17_connect_mongoD_練習\fake.py", line 38, in <module>
    insert_values_json['time'] = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Answer (score 2):

I understand you want to add your own timestamp record. You can use datetime to generate the date. You need to pass the date to your update along with the other data. I haven't tested this, but something like:

```
from datetime import datetime

insert_values_json = json.loads(newvalues_str)

current_utc_time = datetime.utcnow()
for item in insert_values_json:
     item['updated_time']= current_utc_time
     item['inserted_time']= current_utc_time

x = insert_db_data(insert_one_or_many, insert_values_json)
print(x)
```

Comment: The output is looks like this `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\chuan\OneDrive\Desktop\10.17_connect_mongoD_練習\3333@@@@.py", line 54, in <module>
    insert_values_json['time'] = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: For "insert_values_json['time'] =" to work "insert_values_json" needs to be a python dictionary. I thought it would be if it was created with json.loads. What does insert_values_json look like after you do json.loads? Can you do a print(insert_values_json)

Comment: I just put print "insert_values_json " and  type  result in question, can u take a look

Comment: Since insert_values_json is a list of dictionaries you would need to add the time to each item in the dictionary. 

I'm assuming when you use the 'one' option that insert_values_json is still a list of dictionaries.

I've updated the answer.

Comment: but we are manually adding time `'time': datetime.datetime(2022, 10, 19, 3, 13, 1, 315356)}` to every single data, this should not be what we want for human or user to do . In the output record I post on top MOngoDB **already record the auto time** such as  `/* 1 createdAt:2022/10/18 上午11:29:51*/` and `/* 2 createdAt:2022/10/18 上午10:25:35*/`  ; which I mentioned on question (( _I see the system does contain this, can we just extract this and add to my time block. Maybe that one of the way/* 1 createdAt:2022/10/18 上午11:29:51*/_ )) I want grab the auto modified time whatever we change on data

Comment: ur suggestion is adding time when input data (mongoDB's data is pretty huge, doing like this might not efficent), and that shoud be the "auto generate modify time"  where we can just grab and use it

Comment: "this should not be what we want for human or user to do" Definitely not. I'm adding it through code in the example.

""auto generate modify time" where we can just grab and use it" I'm not sure how you want to use it.  
The discussion you linked to seems to suggest that oid.generation_time doesn't keep track of update times....do you only need the insert time and never an updated time?

Comment: I want both insert time and update time , that any last modify time, how do we do it??

Comment: Personally, I'd still do it the way that I suggested. I updated my answer to include an entry for inserted time and updated time for the insert. Wherever you do your updates in your code, the idea would be the same, except that you would just update the relevant fields. Not the inserted time.

If you would prefer to access the date stored with object id when a document is created the python code is ObjectId('[]').generation_time. [There's an example here where someone accesses generation_time after filtering docs.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52037802/1586014)